# How to auto generate number in ascending form?

Tags: java

Input :

```
1001
1003
1004
1005
```

Output

```
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
```

Are there any examples using **JAVA** to auto generate the number in ascending form? Let say,  if the system check the number 1001 to 1005 and 1002 is missing, the system will auto generate 1002.

Comment: something like a loop?

Comment: yes, another example if 1001 to 1005 and 1004 is missing then the system will auto generate 1004 for you.

Comment: How do you get the input? Is it necessarily sorted?

Comment: Is the first number encountered always the smallest? If so then it's quite easy - if not it needs thought.

Comment: Reply to @Bathsheba, the first number will always smaller than the last number.

Comment: Reply to @Mureinik, No.... The system does not need any input. The system will only check the missing number.

Comment: Please share, what you have attempted. I encourage you to try it on your own and ask if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: @NoName the missing number of **what**? Are these values hardcoded somewhere? If so, please share this code.

Comment: Reply to @ansh, I have try it by using Random class but the random class will only generate the number in this form EG: 1 3 2 5 7 and so on.

Comment: Reply to @Mureinik, the number is auto generate... Example above just only shows that  the numbers 1001 to 1005 are in text file and some number like 1002 is missing, are there any possible way to use java code generate 1002 for you?

Comment: And why is this downvoted? Looks pretty clear to me.

Comment: So you want to read a text file containing a list of numbers in ascending sequence but might have gaps, and have the program output the same list but with the gaps filled in?

Comment: Reply to @KevinAnderson, yes...

Comment: Reply to @KevinAnderson, but i feel it's no different between hard-code the number using array and the number written in text file.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the examples below are good for me to practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find the smallest value, and then the largest, and generate numbers in between them.

For example,

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1001,1003,1004,1005);
int min = Collections.min(list);
int max = Collections.max(list);
IntStream.range(min, max+1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This is good example and i will take it as my reference. Thanks

Comment: On the right lines but there is no need to load all the numbers into memory.

Comment: @Bathsheba couldn't understand what you were trying to say. Is this in regard to the fact that the first element is the smallest ?

Comment: Apologies. I'm a silly old cat. For some reason I thought the list was in a file. Have an upvote.

Comment: Reply to @Bathsheba, the list of numbers can be in the text file or hard-coded.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop with some condition for example :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(1001, 1003, 1004, 1005));
for (int i = 1001; i < 1005; i++) {
    if (!list.contains(i)) {//if the list not contain this element
        list.add(i);//add this element to the list
    }
}
Collections.sort(list);//sort your list
System.out.println(list);//print your list
```

*Output*

```
[1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005]
```

---

**Solution 2**

You can also use a Set for example :

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1001, 1003, 1004, 1005));
for (int i = 1001; i < 1005; i++) {
    set.add(i);//add element the set
}
```

Comment: Isn't just writing all numbers from 1001 to 1005 the much easier solution?

Comment: There is no need to check the input list at all, except to determine the range (the smallest and largest number in it). In particular, you don't even need to store it (the calculation can be done while reading and discarding it).

Comment: this is another solution @Thilo i like it, but Shashwat already use it in his answer it is late :)

Comment: This is understandable example, i will take it as my reference. Thanks

Comment: This has unnecessary complexity given that you are tending towards such an obvious output scheme.